# Creating events for dynamically created Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery. I was creating a dynamic query for generating buttons. Here the problem I am facing is - the button starts firing during the Loading of the button event. The query is given below.

```
priv.buildFilter = function () {
     $.each(priv.buttonsNames, function (index, value) {
     var divButton = $("<div>");
                    
         if (priv.lineAuditData.endDateTime == null)
           priv.filterButtons.buttons[index] = $("<button>")
           .attr("Id", "StartAudit").addClass("btn btn-primary")
           .addClass("btn-success").append($("<i>").addClass("fas fa-play").css("font-size","25px")
           .css("margin-top", "27px"))
                        //.click("click", function (event) {
                        //    if (event.data !== undefined)
                        //        priv.startAudit();
                        //})
            .click(this, priv.startAudit)
                        ;
        }
}

 priv.startAudit = function () {
        alert("ON");
}
```

Required OutPut : Button need not fires during the filter button binding. But needs to fire when clicking the button

Kindly help me out, with relevant documents

Comment: after adding   .on('click', function () { priv.startAudit(); }) too same effect..

Comment: Can you provide a more complete sample with code only related to the issue (eg perhaps without the $.each / localstorage parts) - enough to demonstrate the issue.- see [mcve]

Comment: The code is quite straight forward, and you're binding click event correctly as documented so I suggest you try to find problem elsewhere.
One addition note: You're looping through `priv.buttonsNames` and you're binding click event to `priv.filterButtons`, is that exactly what you want?

Comment: Yes.. @Dinh Tran, but I dont want to fire the click event during the button loading.